# How to received messages without Notifications even background fetch is turn off

Tags: ios, swift, whatsapp, background-fetch, silent-notification

Anyone know about how to achieve received messages in terminated mode without showing any notification and turn off background fetch in settings ?

In whatsapp application if I mute any conversation and from settings turn off background app refresh , turn off notifications , after when sender send messages , he got delivered response , when I turn-off my internet and open whatsapp application that all 60-70 any number of messages are already received !

I tried with background silent push with FCM but soon if I open any other application , I'm not able to getting silent push. I tried with all versions from iOS 13.5 to iOS 14.3 but all have same output.

How to achieve to load/insert data in terminated application , with turn off background app refresh , notifications ?

Comment: whatsapp, signal, telegrams  is working in socket based concept ,

Comment: In socket based concept also at least for background terminated state socket should disconnect right ?

Comment: WhatsApp has a special unlimited voip push entitlement from Apple that is no longer available.

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for reply, even I think as same like you , is it any possibility to achieve unlimited voip push entitlement from Apple same like whatsapp ?

Comment: No https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/130650

Answer (score 0):

Entitlements are flags that become part of your signed app. These allow you access to various things like APNS, iCloud, Siri, Apple Pay etc. (Your provisioning profile needs to match, otherwise your app won’t start.)

Entitlements can allow you get data even when you are using your app, background fetch, location, getting data even if app is in kill mode, Only need to have APNS attached with any third party from where you can get data like-: Amazon SNS, firebase, twilio etc

Comment: Issue is regarding how to achieve scenario as add entry in application with disabled all notification/background fetch like whatsapp . As silent notification is not any type of reliable solution.